# When authors takes maths with a pinch of a salt

Tags: reference-works

This thread aims to collect mathematical books where authors deal with serious topics and offbeat humour.

Answer (score 5):

MW Hirsch, S Smale, RL Devaney,
*Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos*,
Academic press (2012)

[image]